Azure storage account connection errors "This request is not authorized to perform this operation, ErrorCode:AuthorizationFailure"
I am building a Web app to read files from a blob storage account and compute specific metrics. This app will be deployed as an Azure web app resource, restricted to users connected via the company VPN. The web app and the storage account are configured to operate on private endpoints, ensuring they are inaccessible from the public web.
The App is deploying through Azure pipelines as a code and we have created a service connection.
The web app resource has been assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor and Storage Queue Data Contributor roles in the storage account resource.
To read data from the storage account, I use a connection string configured with all permitted services, resource types, and permissions and HTTPS only for allowed protocols. The script to fetch the necessary data from storage is as follows:
def fetch_access_data(connection_string, admin_container_name, access_blob_name):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=admin_container_name, blob=access_blob_name)
    stream = io.BytesIO(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
    df_access = pd.read_excel(stream)
    return df_access

This script is intended to retrieve the files each user is authorized to access and serves as the first attempt to connect and read data from the storage account.
The error is:

HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:RequestId Failure Content: AuthorizationFailureThis request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:RequestId  Time:2024-11-12T07:44:22.7022630Z

Using the same connection string in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer allows full access to the storage account, including downloading and uploading files without any issues.

We tried to alter the connection string by adding to it the endpoint IPs.
Making the storage account accessible to only specific IP addresses and virtual networks.

The same error keeps occurring.

@G Foutzopoulos Is your web app correctly integrated with the VNet associated with the storage account? The VNet should be configured to allow access to private endpoint resources.

Yes, the web app is correctly integrated with the VNet.

I was able to read files from Azure Blob Storage both locally and in the Azure Web App using a SAS token.
I have assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Azure Web App and Owner role to the Service Principle as shown below.

app.py :
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import io
import streamlit as st

def fetch_access_data(account_url, sas_token, admin_container_name, access_blob_name):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=sas_token)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=admin_container_name, blob=access_blob_name)
    stream = io.BytesIO(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
    text_data = stream.getvalue().decode('utf-8')  
    return text_data

account_url = "https://<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net/"
sas_token = "<SAS_Token>"
admin_container_name = "kamcontainer"
access_blob_name = "samplekam.txt"
st.title("Azure Blob Storage Text File Viewer")

try:
    text_content = fetch_access_data(account_url, sas_token, admin_container_name, access_blob_name)
    st.subheader("Contents of the file:")
    st.text(text_content)
    
except Exception as e:
    st.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Make sure to add your IP address under  the Network settings in the Azure storage as shown below.

In Azure Web App, You can add your IP address under public network access, connect VNet and NAT gateway as shown below.

Configure your storage account in the Backups in the Azure Web App as shown below.

Azure Web App Output :
I successfully read the files from Azure Blob Storage in the Azure Web App as shown below.

